# screen.width/height give wrong info about screen resolution

Tags: javascript, screen

My screen have resolution 1200 x 800 but this script give me 1429 x 893

```
<script>
if (screen) { 
var str = "Screen width:" + screen.width + "\n" + 
          "Screen height:" +  screen.height;
alert(str);
}
</script>
```

Why it doesn't work?

p.s. On other site this code `screen.width + screen.height` but when run it on localhost it give wrong info.

Comment: Did you try `screen.availWidth` etc. just for fun, and are you sure you did'nt do any zooming (hit ctrl-0).

Comment: @adeneo you are right. It was zooming. Thank you.

Comment: There you go, for some reason `screen` returns the wrong resolution when the browser is zoomed. Hitting ctrl-zero fixes that.

Comment: I see. @adeneo write your answer and I'll accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screen.width) :

> Internet Explorer will take into account the zoom setting when
>   reporting the screen width. It will only return the real width of the
>   screen if the zoom is set to 100%.

So for some reason screen returns the wrong resolution when the browser is zoomed. 
Hitting `ctrl-zero` (zero on numpad) fixes that by zooming to 100%.

Comment: `Ctrl+0` will not always return zoom to 100%. My default zoom is 125%. I've seen other devices that are 150%.

Comment: My zoom level is 100% and Internet Explorer still displays the wrong resolution.